# Getting a syntax error while storing a data in sqflite databse in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

Hello Guys I am working on a flutter project Where I am trying to save data in a sqflite database.I tried different ways like storing it using Json, Map but nothing works than I found the old classic way that is using a raw query to store the data.

This is how I am storing data

```
//Storing data into database
DatabaseHelper().saveRecipe(int.parse(recipes[i+1].recipeID),recipes[i+1].recipeName,recipes[i+1].recipeCategory);

//DatabaseHelper Class:
  Future<String> saveRecipe(int recipesId, String recipesName, String recipesCategory) async {
    try{
      var dbClient = await db;
      await dbClient!.rawQuery('INSERT INTO $recipeTable ($recipeId,$recipeName,$recipeCategory) VALUES ($recipesId,$recipesName,$recipesCategory)');
      return 'Success';
    }catch(e){
      return 'Failure';
    }
  }
```

The error I am getting is

```
E/SQLiteLog( 5185): (1) near "Chicken": syntax error in "INSERT INTO recipeTable (recipeId,recipeName,recipeCategory) VALUES (101,Butter Chicken,Indian Cuisine)"
E/SQLiteLog( 5185): (1) near "Cuisine": syntax error in "INSERT INTO recipeTable (recipeId,recipeName,recipeCategory) VALUES (102,Tikka,Indian Cuisine)"
E/SQLiteLog( 5185): (1) near "Cuisine": syntax error in "INSERT INTO recipeTable (recipeId,recipeName,recipeCategory) VALUES (103,Pizza,Italian Cuisine)"
E/SQLiteLog( 5185): (1) near "Food": syntax error in "INSERT INTO recipeTable (recipeId,recipeName,recipeCategory) VALUES (104,Burger,Fast Food)"
E/SQLiteLog( 5185): (1) near "Cuisine": syntax error in "INSERT INTO recipeTable (recipeId,recipeName,recipeCategory) VALUES (105,Karai,Pakistani Cuisine)"
E/SQLiteLog( 5185): (1) near "Cuisine": syntax error in "INSERT INTO recipeTable (recipeId,recipeName,recipeCategory) VALUES (106,Handi,Indian Cuisine)"
E/SQLiteLog( 5185): (1) table recipeTable has no column named recipeCategory in "INSERT INTO recipeTable (recipeId,recipeName,recipeCategory) VALUES (107,Soup,Starter)"
E/SQLiteLog( 5185): (1) near "Cuisine": syntax error in "INSERT INTO recipeTable (recipeId,recipeName,recipeCategory) VALUES (109,Shawarma,Eastern Cuisine)"
E/SQLiteLog( 5185): (1) near "Fires": syntax error in "INSERT INTO recipeTable (recipeId,recipeName,recipeCategory) VALUES (110,French Fires,Fast Food)"
```

I think i show me error because I have data in two word like in first line `101,Butter Chicken,Indian Cuisine` Because of butter and chicken are two different words so may be it is showing me error. I am not sure about this. Please help me to solve the issue, I appreciate all the effort, thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`). Since you're not quoting the strings you're passing to the insert statement, the database thinks they're part of the insert statement's syntax, and fails on them.

You could quote them, but TBH, a better approach would be to use placeholders - it's both easier and safe if there's a chance these strings can be influenced by user input:

```
await dbClient!.rawQuery(
  'INSERT INTO $recipeTable ($recipeId, $recipeName, $recipeCategory) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', 
  [recipesId, recipesName, recipesCategory]);
```